# how to use Queryresult variable as input in other query in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am doing 1 simple db connection test in Robot framework.I am doing as following-

```
${queryResults1}  Query  <sql query>
```

now I want to use the value of  ${queryResults1} as input to another query. I am doing

```
Execute Sql String   select * from customer where customer_id=${queryResults1}
```

here I am getting error .Execute Sql String doesnot get value of queryresult

how can I do this ?

thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: please show the actual error. You also need to show what the first query is.Are you fetching a whole row? Multiple rows? A single column from a single row?

Comment: I am fetching 1 single value/column in first query as below:-
Select customer_id from device where macadress='<macaddress>'

it returns 1 single value.

and the error is -




20151027 21:32:20.153 :  FAIL : 
DatabaseError: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: have you verified that `${queryResults`}` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: log  ${QueryResults} is returning me [(629351,)]   but when I logged ${queryResults[0][0]} ,I got the correct value 629351.

Comment: Have you tried using `${queryResults[0][0]}` in your second query?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your first query is returning a list of tuples -- a list of rows, each of which is a tuple of columns. Even though you're apparently expecting a single value from a single column in a single row, the data is still in this format. You need to pull the value out of that list of tuples before passing it to your second query.

For example:

```
Execute Sql String   select * from customer where customer_id=${queryResults1[0][0]}
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan.I am new to Robotframework so I am getting stuck almost everytime I use a key :)